# how to generate a reverse timestamp with hbase shell

Tags: hbase

I am trying to use a reverse timestamp to generate my rowKey for Hbase.
my rowkey will be an ID followed by a reversed timestamp "ID Reversed timestamp".

I understand that we use this technique to get the last insertion of this ID when we do a scan but how Can I generate this reverse timestamp in Hbase.

Comment: please share some of the code that you have attempted to write.

Answer (score 0):

/**** Use this snippet to put Id having rts. this will make sure Id is always associated with latest rts ***/

```
long rts = Long.MAX_VALUE - new Date().getTime(); 
byte[] rowKey = String.format("%s%s", ID, rts); 
Put put = new Put(rowKey);
```

/***   Get the latest mapping for the given Id ****/

```
String startRow = String.format("%s", String.format(ID));
String endRow = String.format("%s", String.format(ID) + 1l)));
Scan scan = new Scan(startRow.getBytes(), endRow.getBytes());
```